# Tapestry5 Logout exception

Tags: jakarta-ee, tapestry, openejb

I am facing a strange issue and am not able to find out the root cause. Here is the problem statement.

I have one tapestry page with a logout button. When I click on the logout button, the code below is executed and I get the exception.

```
// method which called onclick of logout button. 
@OnEvent(value = EventConstants.ACTION, component = "tlogout")
public Object logout()
{
    request.getSession(false).invalidate();
    return "Login";
}
```

Exception is:

```
INFO  | net.awl.tapestry5.kawwa.services.KawwaModule.TabLocator | 2011-01-05 14:33:23,321
   > Checking for any UPDATES

INFO  | net.awl.bfi.websuite.services.AppModule.TimingFilter | 2011-01-05 14:33:23,352
   > Request time: 31 ms

ERROR | org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/WebSuiteMoreaTapestry].[default] | 2011-01-05 14:33:23,352
   > Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2221)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2031)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:832)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:843)
    at net.atos.xa.rm.jaas.openejb.web.RMOpenEJBFilter.doFilter(RMOpenEJBFilter.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.openejb.tomcat.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:875)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

Guys any idea? 
Regards,
Mahendra

Comment: As your method does not appear in the stack trace, it seems to execute fine, but `net.atos.xa.rm.jaas.openejb.web.RMOpenEJBFilter` is trying to use/create a session after you have invalidated it, which fails.

Does the exception happen on the same request as the logout, or is it after the redirect to the login page?

Comment: Henning i think it is for the same request as the logout. because i tried to put system.out.print in @SetupRender method of Login page but it didn't print anything on console. Next point is that i checked <code>net.atos.xa.rm.jaas.openejb.web.RMOpenEJBFilter</code> doFilter method and found that it is getting some attributes from session and that's why i am getting error. but it is an filter, so it is going to be called after each request/response. so does it means that i can not invalidated the session?

Comment: a filter can do it's work before or after the request is processed. perhaps you need to notify openejb that the session is invalidated. i would have a look at it's source code, docs etc. i don't think this is a tapestry issue. tagging incase openejb people have ideas.

Comment: yes this is because of the RMOpenEJBFilter. Can we bypass the Filter for a selected request/response without modifying the Filter source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your time and your comments! With some good discussion I finally found the solution and are sharing it with you.

In my case request/response coming through `RMOpenEJBFilter`. So, when I invalidated the session in my code then it crashed in `RMOpenEJBFilter` because its internal code process on session.

So here is my solution.

1. I created one Filter named as `LogOutFilter`.
2. in WEB.XML I put it before `RMOpenEJBFilter` (for the purpose of Filter Chaining).
3. in my logout code i am setting one variable in session

`request.getSession(false).setAttribute("InvalidateSession", true);`

1. so when I click on the logout button it sets the session attribute, then goes to the `RMOpenEJBFilter` where it process the request (till the time session is not invalidated). Now control goes to the `LogOutFilter` where I made a check to invalidate the session.

`if (httpRequest.getSession(false) != null &&  httpRequest.getSession(false).getAttribute("InvalidateSession") != null) {
                httpRequest.getSession(false).invalidate();
            }`

And now it's working fine.

Hope my solution is good enough to be accepted.

Feel free to contact me for any clarification.

Regards,
Mahendra Athneria
Mumbai, India

Comment: i'm sure that would work, however i'd expect openejb would have a way of avoiding the situation...

Comment: yes you are right. but that is not in my control thats why i have created my own filter to sort out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i think u don't need filter. just add following action for logout.

```
@OnEvent("Logout")
    private Object onActionFromLogout() {
        Session session = requestGlobals.getRequest().getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            session.invalidate();
        }

        return Login.class;
    }
```